# Android. Mockito uses real objects instead of mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito, kotlin

So, I've just writing simple test. 
The problem is that test runner runs real 'Repository' class code instead of mock code...
Do you have any idea why could I get an exception on this?

Test class

```
class SingInFacebookPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var view: SignInFacebookContract.View

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    @Captor
    private lateinit var callback: ArgumentCaptor<RepositoryCallback.FacebookLoginImp>

    private lateinit var presenter: SingInFacebookPresenter

    private val serverToken = "token"

    @Before
    fun init() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        presenter = SingInFacebookPresenter(MockContext(), repository, view)
    }

    @Test
    fun facebook_login_success() {

        //Given
        val token = "token"
        val serverToken = "server token"

        presenter.loginViaFacebook(token)

        //When
        verify(repository).loginViaFacebook(token, callback.capture())


        callback.value.onSuccess(serverToken)

        //Then
        verify(view).success(serverToken)
    }
```

Presenter

```
class SingInFacebookPresenter(var context: Context, var repository: Repository, var view: SignInFacebookContract.View): SignInFacebookContract.Presenter {

    public override fun loginViaFacebook(token: String) {
        repository.loginViaFacebook(token, object : RepositoryCallback.FacebookLoginImp {
            override fun onSuccess(token: String) {
                view.success(token)
            }

            override fun onFailure() {
                view.onFailure()
            }

        })
    }
```

Repository

```
open class Repository(context: Context) {

    init {
        ApiHelper(context)
    }

    private var facebookLoginPresenterCallback: RepositoryCallback.FacebookLoginImp? = null

    fun loginViaFacebook(token: String, facebookLoginPresenterCallback: RepositoryCallback.FacebookLoginImp?) {
//        this.facebookLoginPresenterCallback = facebookLoginPresenterCallback
        val signInResponse = ApiHelper.signInViaFacebook(token)
//        signInResponse.enqueue(signInFacebookCallback)
        signInResponse.enqueue(object : Callback<SignInResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SignInResponse>?, response: Response<SignInResponse>?) {
                if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
                    val token = response.body()?.token ?: return
                    facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onSuccess(token)
                    return
                }
                facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onFailure()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SignInResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onFailure()
            }
        })
    }

    private val signInFacebookCallback = object : Callback<SignInResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<SignInResponse>?, response: Response<SignInResponse>?) {
            if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
                val token = response.body()?.token ?: return
                facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onSuccess(token)
                return
            }
            facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onFailure()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SignInResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            facebookLoginPresenterCallback?.onFailure()
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Platform.log(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:157)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Platform.log(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:157)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
No argument value was captured!
You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...
...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called.
Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()

Examples of correct argument capturing:
    ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
    verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
    assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this is a good one. Here's what I found:

The test code is not the problem, Mockito creates real (?) instances of the `Repository` for some reason. Or at least fails to intercept the method calls somewhere?

Anyhow, Here's a completely stripped down example that reproduces the problem with `org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.11`:

```
open class Greeter {
    fun hello() = "hello world"
}

class MockitoJavaExample {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val greeter: Greeter = mock()
        println(greeter.hello()) // prints "hello world" which it shouldn't
    }

}
```

I'm not familiar enough with the internals of Mockito to tell you how this is happening, but switching to using `mockito-inline`, a different mocking method solves this. It also gives you the ability to mock non-`open` classes in Kotlin, which you might want anyway so that you don't have to open up your classes for extension just to test them. With this method, whether or not the class is open, you correctly get `null` returned by the function, so it doesn't use the real implementation.

You can switch to the inline version of Mockito by using `compile 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.7.11'` instead of the `-core` version.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I've spend all day to fix that:)

Comment: I've tried use mockMaker extension for mockito, that actually do the same, but it didn't work...

Comment: The extension solution works for me in some projects/modules, but not in others. No idea why it's so flaky. This one seems to be reliable so far.